# Tcl: howto change the behaviour of nameofexecutable

Tags: python, tcl, tk-toolkit, tix

i have some issues with tcl from a c executable using the python interpreter.
For some reason it can't load the `<fullpath>Tix843.dll`. But when running the python code directly (from python) it does work. The path/name to the dll is correct... 
with a dependency walker i only see that Tkinter tries to load the tix dll but cant find it...

After tracing all kind of paths within tcl I can only detect 1 difference: `nameofexecutable`. When running directly from python it's the path to `python.exe` but when running it from my c executable it is (obviously) the `path/name of the executable`.

In tcl/tk I noticed that the `nameofexecutable` is used to set a lot of paths so i think this causes my problem.

The things i tried to prevent this problem:

1. add the path to the dll to the system path
2. add the path to the dll to `$auto_path` -> no change
3. set the `argv[0]` of the c executable before calling PySys_SetArgv -> no change

Am I doing something stupid or how can I set the `nameofexecutable`? Is there any other way to fix this issue.

edit:
checked again with the dependency walker and now i have relay no clue whats going on...
here the results:

```
00:00:07.800: LoadLibraryExW("C:/Program Files (x86)/Python27/tcl/reg1.2/tclreg12.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) called from "c:\program files (x86)\python27\dlls\TCL85.DLL" at address 0x02468871.
00:00:07.800: Loaded "c:\program files (x86)\python27\tcl\reg1.2\TCLREG12.DLL" at address 0x00440000.  Successfully hooked module.
00:00:07.816: Unloaded "c:\program files (x86)\python27\tcl\reg1.2\TCLREG12.DLL" at address 0x00440000.
00:00:07.816: LoadLibraryExW("C:/Program Files (x86)/Python27/tcl/reg1.2/tclreg12.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) returned NULL. Error: The specified module could not be found (126).
00:00:07.832: LoadLibraryExW("C:/Program Files (x86)/Python27/tcl/reg1.2/tclreg12.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) called from "c:\program files (x86)\python27\dlls\TCL85.DLL" at address 0x0246889C.
00:00:07.832: Loaded "c:\program files (x86)\python27\tcl\reg1.2\TCLREG12.DLL" at address 0x00440000.  Successfully hooked module.
00:00:07.832: Unloaded "c:\program files (x86)\python27\tcl\reg1.2\TCLREG12.DLL" at address 0x00440000.
00:00:07.832: LoadLibraryExW("C:/Program Files (x86)/Python27/tcl/reg1.2/tclreg12.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) returned NULL. Error: The specified module could not be found (126).
00:00:07.925: LoadLibraryExW("C:/Program Files (x86)/Python27/tcl/tix8.4.3/Tix843.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) called from "c:\program files (x86)\python27\dlls\TCL85.DLL" at address 0x02468871.
00:00:07.925: Loaded "c:\program files (x86)\python27\tcl\tix8.4.3\TIX843.DLL" at address 0x04480000.  Successfully hooked module.
00:00:07.925: Unloaded "c:\program files (x86)\python27\tcl\tix8.4.3\TIX843.DLL" at address 0x04480000.
00:00:07.925: LoadLibraryExW("C:/Program Files (x86)/Python27/tcl/tix8.4.3/Tix843.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) returned NULL. Error: The specified module could not be found (126).
00:00:07.941: LoadLibraryExW("C:/Program Files (x86)/Python27/tcl/tix8.4.3/Tix843.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) called from "c:\program files (x86)\python27\dlls\TCL85.DLL" at address 0x0246889C.
00:00:07.956: Loaded "c:\program files (x86)\python27\tcl\tix8.4.3\TIX843.DLL" at address 0x04480000.  Successfully hooked module.
00:00:07.956: Unloaded "c:\program files (x86)\python27\tcl\tix8.4.3\TIX843.DLL" at address 0x04480000.
00:00:07.956: LoadLibraryExW("C:/Program Files (x86)/Python27/tcl/tix8.4.3/Tix843.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) returned NULL. Error: The specified module could not be found (126).
00:00:07.956: LoadLibraryA("shell32") called from "c:\program files (x86)\python27\dlls\TK85.DLL" at address 0x024BBACD.
00:00:07.956: LoadLibraryA("shell32") returned 0x75480000.
```

so it can find the dlls some times but not always and then fails

Answer (score 1):

The `nameofexecutable` property is set during the Tcl library initialization (derived from the argument to `Tcl_FindExecutable()` which I don't know how exactly is being called, but definitely is: it's used to do all sorts of stuff). You can't set it at any other point. However, Tcl does not actually use that value for very much that you can't override.

Instead, you should look into setting the [`TCLLIBPATH`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1787) environment variable to a Tcl list of directories to search for package definitions in. Or you can add directories to the `auto_path` global variable inside Tcl (with `lappend auto_path`) which contains the *actual* list of places to look (well, it actually looks in immediate subdirectories of the places listed in that variable as well). This has to be done before you try to load Tix, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the C program cannot find Tix.dll because it is not in your path. Python can find it because it is in the same directory as the python executable, or in a subdirectory that python knows about. Try adding the dll path to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, i did try that but with no success... it actually gives the correct path to the dll and says it cant load it (or a dependent library...) i checked with the dependency walker but that only says that Tkinter cant load the <fullpath>Tix.dll... so no idea how to fix this